# How to feed the jndi configuration from java code instead of having in tomcat server.xml

Tags: tomcat, jndi

We have spring boot project and we able to config the JNDI through java code by creating the bean for **TomcatEmbeddedServletContainerFactory** class.Have the below snippet in our project and working fine with spring boot embedded server.

**But how to make similar kind of JNDI configuration from Java code itself to run the external tomcat server, instead of having in server.xml in Tomcat.**

```
@Bean
public TomcatEmbeddedServletContainerFactory tomcatFactory() {
        return new TomcatEmbeddedServletContainerFactory() {

            @Override
            protected TomcatEmbeddedServletContainer getTomcatEmbeddedServletContainer(
                    Tomcat tomcat) {
                tomcat.enableNaming();
                return super.getTomcatEmbeddedServletContainer(tomcat);
            }

            @Override
            protected void postProcessContext(Context context) {
                ContextResource resource = new ContextResource();
                resource.setName(connectionJndiName);
                resource.setType(DataSource.class.getName());
                resource.setProperty("driverClassName",
                        connectionDriverClassName);
                resource.setProperty("url", connectionURL);
                resource.setProperty("password", connectionPassword);
                resource.setProperty("username", connectionUserName);

                context.getNamingResources().addResource(resource);
            }
        };
}
```

Comment: one more option to do that is have .yml configuration which would be used from java, maybe it helps :)

Comment: Yes, I have tried. It is not working. Suppose we are making JNDI name as part of yml file then spring boot considering that rest of data source configuration like driver,database url will be configured at server level. Its not taking from yml.

Comment: Can you please someone help on this?